# How to set the 'COMPILATION' tag in iTunes using taglib-sharp?

Tags: c#, itunes, taglib-sharp

Is it possible to set the **COMPILATION** tag in iTunes using taglib-sharp?

Unfortunately, there seems to be nothing similar to this:

```
TagLib.File tagFile = TagLib.File.Create(file);  //.m4a file
tagFile.Tag.IsComilation = true;
tagFile.Save();
```

If not natively supported, is it possible to add an custom tag? Possibly through the use of `TagLib.Mpeg4.AppleTag` or `TagLib.Mpeg4.AppleAdditionalInfoBox`?

There are a lot of questions answered here on how to do this using Id3v2 tags, however not for iTunes tags. I also could not find any helpful documentation.

Any help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [official specifications](http://id3.org/Home) of ID3, you seem to be searching for the [`TCMP (iTunes Compilation Flag) Text Frame`](http://id3.org/iTunes%20Compilation%20Flag). Set it to the appropriate value and iTunes will do the rest obviously. The `TCMP Text Frame` takes a boolean value.

> This is a simple text frame that iTunes uses to indicate if the file is part of a compilation.
>
> ```
>  1 if part of a compilation
>  0 or not present if not part of a compilation
> ```

So you can set it like this:

```
TagLib.File tagFile = TagLib.File.Create(file);
Id3v2.Tag tag = (Id3v2.Tag)tagFile.GetTag(TagTypes.Id3v2, true);
tag.SetTextFrame(FrameType.TCMP, "1"); // Change value accordingly...
tagFile.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

To make Farhan's answer work in TagLibSharp v2.3.0 I had to implement it something like this:

```
var mp3File = TagLib.File.Create(destTrackFile);                        
TagLib.Id3v2.Tag tag = (TagLib.Id3v2.Tag)mp3File.GetTag(TagLib.TagTypes.Id3v2, true);
TagLib.ReadOnlyByteVector TCMP = "TCMP";
tag.SetTextFrame(TCMP, "1");
mp3File.Save();
```